# Unknown or bad timezone (2023-01-04)

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error. I am new to laravel and don't know how to solve this. Please help

this is my function in AttendaceController ;

```
function record(Request $req)
{
    $from = now($req->from_date);
    $to = now($req->to_date)->addDays(5);

    $studentAttendance = attendance::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
    
    return view('user_record', ['details' => $studentAttendance]);
}
```

Comment: you should make sure that the `$req->from_date` and `$req->to_date` variables contain valid dates and timezones, and that the timezone you are passing to the `now` function is a valid timezone recognized by PHP. You can set the default timezone in the `config/app.php` configuration file

Comment: `now()` accepts a timezone as a parameter. You are passing something that is probably not a timezone. As the time suggests `now()` returns the date **now**. If you want to parse a specific different date then use `Carbon::parse(...)`